# How to remove spaces in a list of strings in python?

Tags: python

I have been looking through the forums and questions asked on the site about my question and none of them seem to work!

I have been doing a python 3 program in school where I want to remove the spaces from the list of numbers from 1 to 1000. I have made a text document of the numbers and importing them into a list, but when they are put into the list they include spaces which I cannot have.

I have tried all of the methods and they seem to split every number up but they do not stay together in their original numbers.

```
    number = []

    f = open('test.txt', 'r')
    file_contents = f.read()
    List = file_contents
    f.close()

    for i in List:
        number.append(i)

    for i in number:
        if i == '':
        number.remove(' ')

    print(number)
```

This is what the outcome gives me:
`['0', ' ', '1', ' ', '2', ' ', '3', ' ', '4', ' ', '5', ' ', '6', ' ', '7', ' ']` and so on.

Can you help me solve this?

Comment: BTW, how does the list look for numbers > 10? I'd assume it's something like `[..., '1', '0', ' ', '1', '1', ' ', '1', '2', ...]`. Is that how it should be? Instead of removing the spaces, maybe you should improve the way you read the numbers from the file. For this, we should know how the file looks.

Comment: Don't remove items from a list while looping over it, see [Loop "Forgets" to Remove Some Items](//stackoverflow.com/q/17299581) for why, [Remove items from a list while iterating](//stackoverflow.com/q/1207406) for the correct way of doing this.

Comment: vks I tried that and it did not seem to work and that is why i posted on here. tobias_k It looks exactly like you have shown there. Martjin Pieters I will have a look at what you have suggested thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you just made a typo in the code: You check whether the element is an empty string`''`, where you actually wanted to check whether it's a space `' '`.

```
for i in number:
    if i == ' ':  # ' ' instead of ''
        number.remove(' ')
```

However, removing elements from a list while iterating that same list is not good practice and can lead to some surprising results. It seems to work in this case, but don't even get into the habit. Instead, use a list comprehension to filter out the unwanted items.

```
number = [n for n in number if n != ' ']
```

If you also want to convert the number-strings into actual numbers, use this:

```
number = [int(n) for n in number if n != ' ']
```

---

However, there seems to be another problem with the way you read the file. You read the entire content of the file into one string, which I can only assume looks like this: `"1 2 3 4 ... 11 12 13 ... 451 452 ..."`. Then, you convert each *character* from that string into a number, i.e. instead of `451, 452`, you end up with `'4', '5', '1', ' ', '4', '5', '2'`. Instead of iterating over each character, `split` the string first

```
List = file_contents.split()  # added .split()
```

This way, you won't even need  to remove the spaces afterwards, as those are already removed with the `split`.

You can do all this in one (well, two) lines using the `with` and a single list comprehension:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    number = [int(n) for n in f.read().split()]
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful information! See I have only been using python for 2 ish years now a secondary school level so i try to do things with the code I know, I would never had thought of some of the things you have suggested. Unfortunatly I cannot access the files until a later date so I cannot try out any of your methods but I will let you know how I got on.
Once again, thanks for the help!

Comment: I tried this and this worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Can fix it with by replace lines 11 to 13 with code as below:

```
number = [i for i in number if i != ' '] # To exclude empty space from array

# Or

number = [i.strip() for i in number if i.strip()] # To remove space of each element
```

Comment: The second version adds empty elements. You'd have to add a `if i.strip()` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like that

```
number = []

f = open('test.txt', 'r')
file_contents = f.read()
f.close()

for i in file_contents:
    if i.strip():
        number.append(i)

print(number)
```

Comment: or you can use like this  list(filter(lambda a : a.strip(), number))

Comment: I never though of using ".strip()" because we do not get taught that so I will try to use it, thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

First of all it would be interesting to know how this list.txt document exactly looks like. Keep proper line endings in mind.

To get rid of the spaces you could go various ways. I guess I would go with something like this:

```
 [ x.strip() for x in data.readlines() if x.strip().isdigit() ]
```

which is a list comprehension, which returns a list

Comment: The text document literally looks like a list of numbers with spaces up to 1000. 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15..... I am sorry I did not add this in as I was at the end of my lesson while writing this post so I could not include it as I didn't have enough time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
list =   ['0', ' ', '1', ' ', '2', ' ', '3', ' ', '4', ' ', '5', ' ', '6', ' ', '7', ' ']
list = filter(lambda x:x != ' ', list)
for i in list:
        number.append(i)
print(number)
```

I got this result :['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']

Comment: I will be sure to try this and I will let you know how I get on with it. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score -1):

you can use filter function or recursion:

```
def removal(yourlist):
    if yourlist[0]==[' ']:
        return removal(yourlist[1:])
    if yourlist[0]!=[' ']:
        return yourlist[0]+removal(yourlist[1:])
```

Comment: This will fail for lists with length > `sys.getrecursionlimit()`, and is terribly inefficient to boot (re-creating the list object N times).

Comment: yeah xd, but using the filter() function is efficient xd (right?)

Comment: A list comprehension would be more efficient, actually.